# Background menu bar stuff visible through current menu bar

Tags: macos, menu-bar

So this is happening to my menu bar(Look carefully at the menu bar).Looks like menu bar of other apps is visible through it.

[image: Screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Making the menu bar opaque solves it but I liked the transparent thingy.

Have restarted the computer but it's still the same.Any idea on what's causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desktop background is a screen-shot that includes a menu bar. Try going into `System Preferences > Desktop & Screen Saver > Desktop` and choosing a different background.